# how come my sharedPreferences contains my key even after fresh install?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a MainActivity with the following code:

```
private String getSecurityTokenFromSP() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            PublicMacros.SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return prefs.getString(PublicMacros.authToken, "");
}
```

how come it always returns non-null value even after fresh install?

The MainActivity in my application entry point, nothing happens before that.

Comment: your default value is `""` which is not null. its a empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call getString you provide a default value (which is ""). That's why there is no null object returned. Take a look:

[SharedPreferences.getString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)